# How web app starting by tomcat works internally

Tags: tomcat, webapp2, internal

How exactly a web app is started by  tomcat on tomcat startup. Which  class from the webapp will get loaded first in that process and how does tomcat know that this is the first class to be loaded from w webapp on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about using web.xml, there you can configure your servlets and for example give them a load on startup.